# Image not showing on webpage. was working for a few months

Tags: html, wordpress

I am trying to troubleshoot my wordpress. One this page, https://baseusonlinestore.co.uk/ , the images are not loading:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMeAS.png)

It was working for a few months but not sure what changed in the plugin/background.

Any idea?

Updated the plugins but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked for this issue and saw that the whole problem is due to z-index.

Go to WordPress admin and follow this step `Navigate to Appearance → Customize → Additional CSS` add the below custom CSS here

```
.col-full .image-feature img{
z-index:1;
}
.col-full .image-feature figcaption{
z-index:3;
}
.col-full .image-feature a::before {
z-index:2;
}
```